# Outline Alphabet can not run

Tags: networking, vpn, docker

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Two scenarios:

1. Starting Outline Manager by: `./Outline-Manager.AppImage`
   Outline Mnager GUI is running, but when I paste the beyond command I receive two fails. Can someone explain the two fails please? "Starting Shadowbox" and "Starting Watchtower" I answered "Y" for both answers.

   ```
    sudo bash -c "$(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-server/master/src/server_manager/install_scripts/install_server.sh)"
    > Verifying that Docker is installed .......... OK
    > Verifying that Docker daemon is running ..... OK
    > Creating persistent state dir ............... OK
    > Generating secret key ....................... OK
    > Generating TLS certificate .................. OK
    > Generating SHA-256 certificate fingerprint .. OK
    > Writing config .............................. OK
    > Starting Shadowbox .......................... FAILED
    > The container name "shadowbox" is already in use by another container. This may happen when running this script multiple times. We will attempt to remove the existing container and restart it. Would you like to proceed? [Y/n] Y
    > Removing shadowbox container ................ OK
    > Restarting shadowbox ........................ OK
    > Starting Watchtower ......................... FAILED
    > The container name "watchtower" is already in use by another container. This may happen when running this script multiple times. Would you like to replace this container? If you answer no, we will proceed with the remainder of the installation. [Y/n] Y
    > Removing watchtower container ............... OK
    > Restarting watchtower ........................ OK
    > Waiting for Outline server to be healthy .... OK
    > Creating first user ......................... OK
    > Adding API URL to config .................... OK
    > Checking host firewall ...................... BLOCKED
    OK

    CONGRATULATIONS! Your Outline server is up and running.

    To manage your Outline server, please copy the following line (including curly
    brackets) into Step 2 of the Outline Manager interface:

    `{"apiUrl":"https://***:****/****","certSha256":"***"}`                                                      

    You won’t be able to access it externally, despite your server being correctly
    set up, because there's a firewall (in this machine, your router or cloud
    provider) that is preventing incoming connections to ports 15534 and 30630.

    Make sure to open the following ports on your firewall, router or cloud provider:
    - Management port 15534, for TCP
    - Access key port 30630, for TCP and UDP
   ```

EDIT:

After copy-paste the `sudo bash -c "$(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-server/master/src/server_manager/install_scripts/install_server.sh)"`
I receive the `{"apiUrl":"https://***:****/****","certSha256":"***"}`

After I copy-paste the `{"apiUrl":"https://***:****/****","certSha256":"***"}` into the Outline Manager, I receive this error: `Failed to add display server, one or more properties missing {"apiUrl":"https://***:****/****","certSha256":"***"}`

For this example, I have changed the real `apiUrl` and `certSha256` with `****`

2. Scenario number 2. When I start Outline Manager like:

   ```
   $ sudo wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-server/master/src/server_manager/install_scripts/install_server.sh | bash
   > Verifying that Docker is installed .......... OK
   > Verifying that Docker daemon is running ..... OK
   chmod: changing permissions of '/opt/outline': Operation not permitted

   Sorry! Something went wrong. If you can't figure this out, please copy and paste all this output into the Outline Manager screen, and send it to us, to see if we can help you.
   ```

Any thoughts about these errors please? Thank you.

Comment: It appears to be running based on the output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @OrganicMarble, at the end, I have just edit the main question with the new error, if you have any ideas please. Regards.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am facing the same problem